# Get the html5 video poster in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, html5-video

I have a webview that shows videos for the user to play and I can not see the poster.
[image]
I'm using the follwoing webChromeClient:

```
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
            final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            return bitmap;
        }

        public void onShowCustomView (View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("video/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void onHideCustomView () {
        }
    });
```

I only see the white background.

Comment: You can post screenshot about this?

Comment: I updated the post accordingly

Comment: So, video can't run?

Comment: The video runs, I cannot see the poster

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `super.getDefaultVideoPoster()`, white poster occured because you overrided to draw white bitmap

```js
            @Override
        public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
            //final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
            //Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            //canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            return super.getDefaultVideoPoster();
        }
```

My result:
[image]

**Edited:**

You can work around: Add `#t=1` after `src` in html file `<source src="xyz.mp4#t=1" type="video/mp4">`. It will show frame#1 as poster of video.

Comment: You return `return super.getDefaultVideoPoster();` and still occur white poster?

Comment: No, I olso get that grey play button. I need to see a poster or a frame from the video

Comment: You can work around: Add `#t=1` after src in html file
`<source src="xyz.mp4#t=1" type="video/mp4">`